# If $n$ is an rational, when is $n^{1/n}$ rational?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, irrational-numbers

Given that $n$ is rational, when is $\sqrt[n]{n}$ rational?

We can make a polynomial $x^{n}-n$ whose root is $\sqrt[n]{n}$ and using RRT we can show that there are no rational roots, but in the process we are assuming that $n$ is an integer (coefficients must be integers for RRT to work).

How can we solve this problem?

Comment: I think your title should read "If $n$ is rational, when is $n^{1/n}$ rational?"

Comment: $n^{\frac 1k}$ is rational if and only if $n$ is a $k$powered integer and $n^{\frac 1k}$ is an integer.

Comment: Oh, $n$ is *rational*.  Okay, a little more work but same idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $1/n$ is an integer, it works... conversely, if $(p/q)^{q/p}$ is a rational $a/b$, where $p,q$ are coprime positive (and $a,b$ as well), then $p^q/q^q=a^p/b^p$, both as quotients of coprime positive integers, so $p^q=a^p$.

So if $\pi$ is a prime divisor of $p$ with multiplicity $\nu$ (ie $\pi^{\nu}|p$, $\pi^{\nu+1}$ doesn't divide $p$), then the $\pi$-adic valuation of $p^q$ is $\nu q$. But as $p^q$ is a $p$-th power, said valuation is a multiple of $p$, and thus $p|\nu q$. But as $p$ and $q$ are coprime, $p|\nu$, thus $\nu \geq p$, and hence $p \geq \pi^{\nu} > \nu$, a contradiction. Thus $p=1$ (because $p$ has no prime divisors), whence the conclusion.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last sentence.

Comment: Could you elaborate more and go through it a bit more thoroughly?

Comment: I edited, is it clearer now?

Comment: "But as $p^q$ is a $p$-th power, said valuation is a multiple of $p$, and thus $p|νq$.".   How come it implies that the valuation is a multiple of $p$?

Comment: Let $c=p^q=a^p$. Let $\nu$ be the $\pi$-adic valuation of $p$, $\mu$ that of $a$. Then the $\pi$-adic valuation of $c=p^q$ is $\nu q$, but the $\pi$-adic valuation of $c=a^p$ is $p \mu$. So $p\mu=q\nu$ thus $p|q\nu$.

Comment: What would happen if it was instead $p^q=a^{p-q}$? Using a similar method as above I'm able to get to $p \ge \pi^v > v+\mu$ but I'm not sure that the latter inequality holds?

Comment: You'd need to do stuff more carefully. I'm not entirely sure what would happen. Basically you need $p$ to be a $p-q$-th power, but the same reasoning on denominators makes $q$ a $p-q$-th power. But, for each $n \geq 2$, if $a \neq b$ are positive integers, $|a^n-b^n| > n$, so you get a contradiction, unless $|p-q|=1$. As $p^q=a^{p-q}$, we get $a^{p-q} > 1$ so $p-q > 0$ and $n=\frac{p}{p-1}$.

Comment: Sorry - I meant to ask how would we do it if we want to find when $n^{1/(n-1)}$ is rational? Using your method, I got to $p^q = a^{p-q}$ and then I'm trying to move on from there to see if $p$ is necessarily $1$.

Comment: No -- if $n=\frac{p}{p-1}$, you have solutions. I think my comment shows they're the only ones.